# MVC action results in 404 with "No type was found that matches the controller" invoking default action on controller works

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I inherited some ASP.Net MVC code and am tasked with adding some new features. I am a complete beginner using ASP.Net MVC and come from a background of mainly using Web Forms.

I added a new controller (ApiController) and I added the following actions to it:

```
    // GET: /Api/Index
    public string Index()
    {
        return "API Methods";
    }

    // GET: /Api/DetectionActivity
    public JsonResult DetectionActivity()
    {
        var detections = from d in db.Detections
                         orderby DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.CreationTime)
                         group d by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.CreationTime) into g
                         select new { date = g.Key, count = g.Count() };
        ViewBag.DetectionCounts = detections.ToList();
        return Json(detections, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My RouteConfig.cs has the following registered routes.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This looks like the tutorials I've been reading but it's not working and I'm probably missing something.

If I go to localhost:21574/api I see the output from the Index() action, "API Methods".

If I go to localhost:21574/api/DetectionActivity it throws a 404 with the following data in the response:

```
{
    "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:21574/Api/DetectionActivity'.",
    "MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'DetectionActivity'."
}
```

I'm thinking there is something I need to do that I'm not.

Any suggestions on what to do next?

**Update 1**

I tried this with my RouteConfig.cs

```
        routes.MapRoute(name: "ApiController",
            url: "{controller}/{action}"
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

These were my results:

If I go to localhost:21574/api I see the output from the Index() action, "API Methods". Same as before.

If I go to localhost:21574/api/DetectionActivity it throws a 404 with the following data in the response:

```
{
    "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:21574/Api/DetectionActivity'.",
    "MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'DetectionActivity'."
}
```

Same as before.

If I go to localhost:21574/Api/Api/DetectionActivity it throws a 404 with this data in the response:

```
{
    "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:21574/Api/Api/DetectionActivity'.",
    "MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'Api'."
}
```

Now it's saying it can't find a controller named "Api".

Comment: Does this application also define WebAPI routes?  Usually the "/api" part of the URL is reserved for that, and may be causing confusion with an `ApiController`.

Comment: BTW for ApiController the route configuration done in WebApiConfig class not RouteConfig.cs

Comment: I'm not using WebAPI routes as I haven't done any research/reading on them yet. But it sounds like it might be worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

from your Route Config
the URL should be: `localhost:21574/Api/Dashboard/DetectionActivity`

or if you really need `localhost:21574/Api/DetectionActivity` (not recommended)

change your `Register` method in `WebApiConfig` class to

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: Using http://localhost:21574/api/Dashboard/DetectionActivity results in "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Dashboard'."

Comment: If I try using http://localhost:21574/Dashboard/Api/DetectionActivity I get another 404 but the message is "A public action method 'Api' was not found on controller 'DashboardController'."